# How to "pass around" function environments with local variables in Lua

Tags: function, lua

Please consider the following snippet of code.

```lua
-- file A.lua
function A()
    local x = 1
    local y = 2
    if ... then
        --super hidden code that should not be seen
        x += 1
        y += 1
        -- over
    end
end
```

How would I be able to move the contents of the `if` statement outside of the function `A`, while not changing any code inside of it?

Effectively achieving the following result

```lua
-- file A.lua
function A()
    local x = 1
    local y = 2
    if ... then
        require("B.lua")()
    end
end
```

```lua
-- file B.lua
return function B()
    x += 1
    y += 1
end
```

This sound foolish, but I need to create a generator script that copy & pastes certain pieces of code and separates them into different files.
I've tried using `getfenv()` and `setfenv()`, but the problem is that local variables do not get passed around with the function environment, requiring some (?) other workaround to pass them.

Please don't question the need for this. I am really desperate.

Below is my attempt at the previously mentioned `getfenv()`, `setfenv()` idea.

```lua
-- file A.lua
function A()
    local x = 1
    local y = 2
    if ... then
        require("B.lua")(getfenv(1))
    end
end
```

```lua
-- file B.lua
return function B(__fenv)
    setfenv(1, __fenv)
    x += 1
    y += 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You're not using Lua. Lua doesn't have a `+=` operator. You're probably using Luau or a Lua preprocessor. You seem to have `setfenv` and `getfenv` available though.

> Please don't question the need for this.

There is no need for this in your example; if you have an example where there is a need for this, please provide it.

Most likely you should refactor your code to eliminate the locals, using a table instead, in order to extract part of it into a function:

```lua
function A()
    local t = {x = 1, y = 2}
    if ... then
        B(t)
    end
end

function B(t)
    t.x += 1
    t.y += 1
end
```

Alternatively, you could pass the values of `x, y` to `B` and return the new values:

```lua
function A()
    local x = 1
    local y = 2
    if ... then
        x, y = B(x, y)
    end
end

function B(x, y)
    return x + 1, y + 1
end
```

Extracting part of your code into a function will typically make it *easier*, not *harder* to understand. It doesn't *per se* help with "obfuscating" "secret" code. Obfuscating code *by hand* is generally a very poor idea and a great way to shoot yourself in the foot.

---

Just for fun, let's develop a few hacky, inefficient, horrible approaches. Our first approach gives `A` a new environment every time it is called, and changes the environment of `B` to also be this new environment before calling it:

```lua
local function B()
    x += 1
    y += 1
end
function A()
    local env = {}
    setfenv(1, env)
    x, y = 1, 2
    setfenv(B, env)()
end
```

This is pretty dirty. Note how `B` needs to be local to `A`; otherwise it wouldn't be accessible (the entire global table is inaccessible to `A`). Note also that this modifies the environment of `B` and makes no attempt to restore it; this is only fine if `A` is the only callsite of `B`. If there are more callsites, you'd have to restore it, and you'd even have to make sure to do so in a manner which doesn't fail if `B` errors, so you'd have to wrap it in (`x`)`pcall`. It would be cleaner to pass `env` to `B` as an argument, but then again it'd be cleaner to just pass a table `t` around rather than to mess with function environments at all.

To make the global table accessible, you could do `setmetatable(env, {__index = _G})` *before* the call to `setfenv`. That way, all variables which aren't found in `env` (which includes variables you set to `nil`!) will be looked up in the global table `_G`. That way `B` wouldn't need to be a `local` variable anymore. This is a pretty dirty and inefficient hack though; when I mess with function environments, I generally prefer explicitly isolating them and localizing all global variables I use rather than setting an `__index`.

But you wanted locals, not "environmentals" (which are effectively just syntactic sugar for table access where you get to omit the implicit environment table, typically `_G`, being accessed). So let's get even dirtier by involving the `debug` library. We'll write a helper which collects the locals into a table for this:

```lua
local function get_locals()
    local locals, idx = {}, {}
    local i = 1
    while true do
        local name, value = debug.getlocal(2, i) -- stack level 2: caller
        if not name then return locals, idx end
        if name:sub(1, 1) ~= "(" then -- ignore internal variables
            locals[name] = value
            idx[name] = i
        end
        i = i + 1
    end
end
```

now of course you'll also have to change the local variables after `B` is done with them, so let's write a function for that too:

```lua
local function set_locals(locals, idx)
    for name, value in pairs(locals) do
        debug.setlocal(2, idx[name], value)
    end
end
```

now let's put it together:

```lua
function B()
    x += 1
    y += 1
end
function A()
    local x = 1
    local y = 2
    if ... then
        local locals, idx = get_locals()
        setfenv(B, locals)()
        set_locals(locals, idx)
    end
end
```

you'd probably want to refactor

```lua
local locals, idx = get_locals()
setfenv(B, locals)()
set_locals(locals, idx)
```

into a function call `call_with_locals(B)` (hint: to do so, you have to adapt the stack levels `get_locals` and `set_locals` use, or you can just copy-paste their bodies into the new function); you'd also probably want to restore the environment of `B` afterwards.

But let me reiterate: **Don't do this.** It makes your code:

- Much, much less efficient. Locals are very fast, tables are slower, the `debug` library is extremely slow, packing all locals up in a table is very slow.
- Very hacky. Using environments alone is typically a major code smell. I find the only "clean" use is usually a "module" table `_M` which is *completely isolated* from the global environment. Such code will be much harder to understand such it violates assumptions about how variables in Lua work. Linters and language servers will yield wrong results. Also
  note: This doesn't deal with upvalues at all yet.

Comment: I am using Luau indeed, sorry for the inclarity.

As for the actual need for this type of wizardry, I am developing a game and thought it would be a good idea to share both client and server-sided logic inside of one module script, making the whole codebase, in my opinion, much more clear and easier to work with. As the shared logic resides in one script, it must be replicated to the client, making the server-sided code exposed for malicious clients to see. I really want to avoid spliiting my code into three scripts: client, shared and server.

I post more comments becuse i ran out of char

Comment: The idea is that this whole mess that I'm trying to craft with "passing around" all the local variables is that this is gonna be auto-generated, I'm not going to be working with this code. I was thinking I could separate all my "if isServer then ... end" statements into server-sided scripts not when developing my game, but by running a script that would do that for me. And uploading this generated version, instead of the actual, "unobfuscated" one, so that no client has access to actual server code.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but I've forgot to mention that, unfortunately, Luau has a very limited debug library, and does not provide me with functions such as "getupvalues" or "getlocal". At this point I'm not sure why it's even called "debug".

Comment: The only real solution I see is creating a new metatable for each local variable in the scope, which (since there's no debug.getlocal in Luau, hooray!) I would have to somehow (?) possibly collect with a lua parser myself. Now if what you just had is a "dirty hack", this one is real dirty.

Comment: But what could be my other options at this point? I really only have getfenv and setfenv to work with. Also, I really appreciate this long and detailed answer, thank you!

Comment: Refactoring this mess of a codebase would be a nightmare, but also as I've said before, I wouldn't like to separate my scripts

Comment: If you really need to hide server code from the client user, the server code needs to be in a separate git repo, not just a separate file. There's no way to do this without refactoring.

Comment: @luther
https://imgur.com/a/CJ19K0P
In Roblox there's these services, anything that is inside of ReplicatedStorage (which is all of my scripts) is obviously replicated to all the clients, and everything inside of ServerStorage or ServerScriptService is only stored on the server, so it can be inside of a different file, just not under the same service. I want to have all the scripts only inside of ReplicatedStorage, in one place, instead of a bunch of scripts all around the place. And my idea was to create a script that would automatically take away the server-sided pieces of code, cut

Comment: ... them out and put inside of ServerStorage, so that they are only available to the server.

Comment: There's progress. I might have an idea on how this whole lua preprocessor (because I guess that's what it has came down to) would work. Here's an example [source](https://pastebin.com/fPWnsqZM) and its [output](https://pastebin.com/XpnJrY9D). You can see that the affected source code is exactly the same in both versions, and the best part about this - it actually works! (to run the output please navigate to [this website](https://luau-lang.org/demo)) The only thing left is to actually code up this preprocessor and collect all the local variable names using a lexer/parser.

Comment: This output is obviously a primitive prototype and has to be extended to include all the existing metamethods, but the idea is there... hopefully.

Comment: @oimate another way to go about it would be to use a "macro" mechanism, e.g. generating the code for function A by just copy-pasting the function body of function B, assuming you have `loadstring`. Note that none of these approaches allow you to "hide" the "common" code from the client: If code gets executed on the client, it needs to be available to the client at some point, at which point it can also be inspected. You can try to make it harder, but you can't prevent it. Period. Refactoring server-client codebases into server, client and common code is how it's usually done.

Comment: I'm well aware that common code can be seen from the client. It's common, not server-sided. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by a "macro" mechanism?

Comment: @oimate you can write Lua(u) code to generate Lua(u) code using simple string substitution (`gsub`). This is pretty hacky, but it should allow you to effectively "paste" the body of `B` (as a string) into both `A` and the client code (as strings).